# Quick and Easy Server Side Cache?

Tags: java, caching, servlets

Will this setup work as a server-side cache?  Will the values stay in memory and not get GC'ed?

The Servlet gets created on app server start-up, and is the only Servlet in the application.  So, if the Servlet stops, the application closes down.  The app will only ever run across one JVM.

```
public class HtmlServlet extends HttpServlet
{
   private ConcurrentHashMap<String, Object> cache;

   public void init() throws ServletException
   {
      cache = Cache.init();
   }

}

public class Cache
{

  private static ConcurrentHashMap<String, Object> cache;

  public synchronized static ConcurrentHashMap<String, Object> init()
  {
     if (cache == null)
     {
         cache = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, Object>();
     }
     return cache;
  }

  public static void set(String s, Object o) { ... }
  public static Object get(String s) { ... }
  public static void remove(String s) { .. }
}
```

Comment: Your cache impl is fine for topic "Quick and Easy Server Side Cache" but as all "Quick and Easy solutions" it has consequences, some of them are listed in answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to use [WeakHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/WeakHashMap.html). You can also have look at [Guava CacheBuilder](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/cache/CacheBuilder.html), its based on SoftReferences. These two type of references are collected by GC differently. SoftReferences are more suitable for caching, but there is no built-in implementation in JSE.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't look like it has any obvious flaws.
Except maybe the fact that the cache can fill up and crash, since there's nothing that would automatically remove old entries.

If you're not careful when using the cache, you can introduce a subtle memory leak it might keep filling up.

Answer (score 0):

This will work, but it'll also grow without bound, and it's invasive (all your code has to know about the cache; it doesn't implement `Map`). Using a Guava cache might be a more practical choice.

Answer (score 0):

Probably it's not an answer to question you asked, but why don't you want to use something like [EhCache](http://ehcache.org/)? It's already implemented caching solution and works great :)

EDIT
But answering your question - I think your solution also should work :)

Comment: I kept it simple in the question, but my Cache class is actually an abstraction layer, so when the app is deployed only on 1 server, it uses this JVM based cache solution, and when it's deployed to multiple servers, it uses a Memcached based solution.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Servlet` `init` method will be invoked only once/JVM, so there is no need for `synchronized` in your `Cache` `init` method.
You mainly need to `synchronize` methods which will populate your `cache`, and in your case even that's not needed i think, because you are using `concurrenthashmap`

Comment: Thanks, I guess you're right, I can remove the synchronized from the Cache.init() method.  They shouldn't be needed on the get/set/remove functions

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like that, just make sure to wrap all values in `WeakReference`s. You'll still get a growth of keys. You could scan and clear keys, clear keys in the `get` when you notice that the weak reference is invalid, or use a `WeakHashMap` if you don't need the `ConcurrentHashMap` functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You better use the Attributes on the [ServletContext](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#setAttribute%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%29) at least the Tomcat's ApplicationContext uses CHM.